# Users in odd state of pending and needing password reset

Tags: users

Users are falling into the following state:

- Tried to sign up with public registration
- Never clicked or never received (or so they claim) the verification email.
- Users try to sign up and email is already taken
- Users cannot reset password as their account is not verified.

Is this a problem? Or am I missing something. Is there a way to activate when they click the reset password link email?

Apart from resending verification email manually for all 100+ users is there anything else i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... sounds like a registration workflow issue.  If they click on the activation link and it's past the time it's valid, the page does have a link where they can resend it, but that's only going to be helpful if they got the email in the first place.

I think for now you'll have to use the "Resend Activation Email" button in the CP.

Comment: Thanks, should I mark this as the answer to the question?

Comment: Might as well...